# Html.TextAreaFor width doesn't change

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

How to change text area width in ASP.NET MVC View? I read questions about this problem here, but nothing helped.

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Suggestions, new { @class = "text-area", placeholder = "Unesite svoje prijedloge..." })
```

CSS:

```
.text-area {
    width:50%;
    height:100px;
    color:#3A3A3A;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:italic;
}
```

All styles are applied except this for text area width.
I also tried this:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Suggestions, new { rows = "7", cols = "70", @class = "text-area", placeholder = "Unesite svoje prijedloge..." })
```

But no result.

Comment: It looks OK (and worked for me). Use you developer tools to inspect the element and check that the styles are actually being applied.

Comment: try to increase the width through the chrome developer tools and check if its working !

Comment: or maybe your containing block that contains the textarea is preventing it.

Answer (score 8):

Open developer tools and find the input element in your browser. Look to see if there is a max-width property set on your TextArea element. If so then all you need to do is us the following code to overwrite it.

-- You can use this code if you are only binding a single model to your view

```
@Html.TextArea("NameOfElement", Model.propertyName, new {style = "max-width:100% !important;"})
```

--- OR ---

--- Use this code is you are binding a model from a list of models

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.propertyName, new {style="max-width:100%", @id = "ElementId"})
```

Note:

1) If you use the above value for the max width it will inherit from the parent container.

2) The first parameter in the TextArea help is the name of the element. It also assigns the name as the elementID. In the TextAreaFor you have to explicitly assign the elementID as shown above.

Answer (score 2):

Try using *form-control-full* property:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Value, new { @class = "form-control form-control-full", rows = 8})
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<form id="myform">
<textarea value="">
</textarea>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
#myform textarea{
Width: 50%;
height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: But I need to bind this text area to model.Suggestions, how to do that without Razor?

Comment: Do you have the provided Site.css in your project..??

Comment: Bcoz it has the width of textbox and textarea set to 300px and if you have used it in _Layout page then it may be overriding the values..

Comment: @MuditJuneja, I deleted that file (Site.css) and wrote css in another file.

Answer (score 0):

I found this: 
in site.css line 19

/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */

input,

select,

textarea {

```
max-width: 280px;
```

}

remove textarea in this.